# Decorate properties with attributes in a more flexible manner

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-attributes

Lets say I have these class

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class SomeClass : BaseClass
{
  ... more properties ...
}
```

BaseClass is considered to be used on a lot of places.

In my case I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3's EditorForModel to render Views, and it's common to decorate properties with attributes such as `[Display(Name = "Id"), Required]`

But lets say I would want to decorate the properties of BaseClass in different ways for every class that inherits it. In `SomeClass` I may want to decorate `Id` with `[Required]` and in `OtherClass` I might want to decorate it with `[SomeCustomAttribute]`.

Is there a way to this?

It would be nice to be able to do something like this:

```
public class SomeClass : BaseClass
{
  public SomeClass()
  {
    WithProperty(x => x.Id).AddAttribute(new RequiredAttribute());
    ...
  }

  ... more properties ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are static metadata. Assemblies, modules, types, members, parameters, and return values aren't first-class objects in C# (e.g., the System.Type class is merely a reflected representation of a type). You can get an instance of an attribute for a type and change the properties if they're writable but that won't affect the attribute as it is applied to the type

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the property as virtual, and override it in the derived class.  Decorate the override with the class-specific attributes, and the base property with any attributes that should apply to all classes.

Be sure that attributes applied to base properties are not themselves decorated with the `AttributeUsageAttribute` with an `Inherited` value of `false` (the default is `true`).  If an attribute's `AttributeUsage` specifies `Inherited == false` then an overriding property will not inherit the attribute.  See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to decorate the attributes to members for individual object instance level. It is type specific meta-data. If you really need this, you will have to implement your own attribute management dealing with instance specific.